# Weblogic Error: Server state changed to FORCE_SHUTTING_DOWN

Tags: oracle11g, weblogic

It was still working when I closed it last week after I installed and conifigured weblogic server but right now it is not starting. Here are last few statements shown in the cmd:

```
<May 8, 2017 10:08:23 AM CST> <Notice> <Security> <BEA-090898> <Ignoring the tru
sted CA certificate "CN=KEYNECTIS ROOT CA,OU=ROOT,O=KEYNECTIS,C=FR". The loading
 of the trusted certificate list raised a certificate parsing exception PKIX: Un
supported OID in the AlgorithmIdentifier object: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11.>
<May 8, 2017 10:08:23 AM CST> <Notice> <Security> <BEA-090898> <Ignoring the tru
sted CA certificate "CN=GeoTrust Primary Certification Authority - G3,OU=(c) 200
8 GeoTrust Inc. - For authorized use only,O=GeoTrust Inc.,C=US". The loading of
the trusted certificate list raised a certificate parsing exception PKIX: Unsupp
orted OID in the AlgorithmIdentifier object: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11.>
<May 8, 2017 10:08:23 AM CST> <Emergency> <Security> <BEA-090087> <Server failed
 to bind to the configured Admin port. The port may already be used by another p
rocess.>
<May 8, 2017 10:08:23 AM CST> <Error> <Server> <BEA-002606> <Unable to create a
server socket for listening on channel "Default". The address 10.117.20.19 might
 be incorrect or another process is using port 6001: java.net.BindException: Can
not assign requested address: JVM_Bind.>
<May 8, 2017 10:08:23 AM CST> <Error> <Server> <BEA-002606> <Unable to create a
server socket for listening on channel "DefaultSecure". The address 10.117.20.19
 might be incorrect or another process is using port 6002: java.net.BindExceptio
n: Cannot assign requested address: JVM_Bind.>
<May 8, 2017 10:08:23 AM CST> <Critical> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000362> <Server f
ailed. Reason: Server failed to bind to any usable port. See preceeding log mess
age for details.>
<May 8, 2017 10:08:23 AM CST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server sta
te changed to FAILED>
<May 8, 2017 10:08:23 AM CST> <Error> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000383> <A critical
service failed. The server will shut itself down>
<May 8, 2017 10:08:23 AM CST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server sta
te changed to FORCE_SHUTTING_DOWN>

C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\Tiplus_domain>
```

Comment: What have you done to investigate? Is something using that port? Is the IP address correct? I would *guess* that your PC gets its IP address via DHCP and after rebooting it has a different one to last time, so the fixed address in the WebLogic config is no longer correct.

Comment: So if that is the case? What can be my fix if this situation happens to me in my next boot? Because I have reinstalled Weblogic and it is working fine now.

Comment: So did your IP address change? You probably want to have a static IP address and not use DHCP for a server.

Answer (score 0):

check whether your server is already is running... and restart the server... after that is does not start the check the port or check the script ... for check the log file whether the particular port is running or not...

Comment: Please make your answer steps-wise and more informative.